# syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have the following ruby code:

```
  EmailTemplate.for(mailer).each do |template|
    begin
      print '.'
      template.upload(publish)
    rescue Mandrill::UnknownTemplateError
      failed.push(mailer)
    end
  end
```

Rubocop corrected my code to:

```
EmailTemplate.for(mailer).each do |template|
    print '.'
    template.upload(publish)
  rescue Mandrill::UnknownTemplateError
    failed.push(mailer)
  end
```

and now it returns following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting keyword_end
```

How can I fix that?

Rubocop warnings was:

```
C: Style/RedundantBegin: Redundant begin block detected.
```

Comment: What is your Ruby version?

Comment: The first version looks fine to me.

Comment: My Ruby version is 2.4.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, Rubocop thinks you're running Ruby 2.5, not Ruby 2.4.1.

You can fix this one of two ways:

1) Create a file `.ruby-version` with content `2.4.1`. Rubocop should pick up your Ruby version from this file.
2) Add the following to your `.rubocop.yml`:

```
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 2.4
```

Answer (score 10):

Ruby 2.5.0 added a [feature](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12906):

> rescue/else/ensure are now allowed to be used directly with do/end blocks. [Feature #12906]

But before that, it was not allowed. So syntax error will be there.

Lets do syntax test for the code in *sample.rb*:

```
[].each do |a|
  # ops
  rescue Exception => ex
  puts ex.inspect
end
```

From terminal:

```
Ruby$ ruby -c sample.rb
sample.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue
  rescue Exception => ex
        ^
sample.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
Ruby$ rvm use 2.5.1
Using /Users/aruprakshit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
Ruby$ ruby -c sample.rb
Syntax OK
```

See the [News](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_0/NEWS#language-changes). So before 2.5.0, you need to write it like:

```
[].each do |a|
  begin
    # ops
  rescue => Exception
    puts ex.inspect
  end
end
```

You can configure Rubocop to select the version of Ruby you want by following [Setting the target Ruby version](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/manual/configuration.md#setting-the-target-ruby-version).

> Some checks are dependent on the version of the Ruby interpreter which
>   the inspected code must run on. For example, enforcing using Ruby 2.3+
>   safe navigation operator rather than try can help make your code
>   shorter and more consistent... unless it must run on Ruby 2.2.
>
> If .ruby-version exists in the directory RuboCop is invoked in,
>   RuboCop will use the version specified by it. Otherwise, users may let
>   RuboCop know the oldest version of Ruby which your project supports
>   with:

```
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 2.4
```